# How can I calculate the number of days between two dates with different format in Python?

Tags: python, date, datetime, format

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of orderdates formatted like this: 2019-12-26.
However when I take the max of this date it will give 2019-12-12. While it is actually 2019-12-26. It makes sense because my dateformat is Dutch and the max() function uses the 'American' (correct me if I'm wrong) format.
This meas that my calculations aren't correct.

How I can change the way the function calculate? Or if thats not possible, change the format of my date column so the calculations are correct?

```
[In] df['orderdate'] = df['orderdate'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
     print(df["orderdate"].max())
```

```
[Out] 2019-12-12 00:00:00
```

Thank you!

Comment: By converting them to datetime using `to_datetime()`

Comment: Your edit shows an issue. You can't just convert the `dtype`, you need `to_datetime` and to provide a format string so that pandas knows what it's looking at

Comment: @roganjosh So I don't have to use the type conversion? As long as I use to_datetime

Comment: `to_datetime` _does_ do the type conversion, but it allows you to specify how the string is formatted

Comment: @roganjosh I'm very new to Python. But when I use `df['orderdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['orderdate'], format="%d%m%Y")` it throws an error `ValueError: time data '10-12-2019' does not match format '%d%m%Y' (match)`

Comment: Because it doesn't. It would, however, match `"%d-%m-%Y"`. You have to include the non-datetime characters. Even whitespace is important when specifying the format.

Comment: @roganjosh ah yes you are right! Thank you, that did the trick.